# Any way to make lastVal work for a jQuery UI datepicker that is displayed inline?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

As I mentioned above, I'm displaying a jQuery datepicker inline and can't get lastVal working. For further illustration I've edited a [jQuery datepicker with working lastVal](https://jsfiddle.net/edmx1kqv/) to [displaying inline](https://jsfiddle.net/do3kwvs5/) and didn't change anything else and it doesn't work. lastVal is always undefined.

My current jQuery code looks like this:

```
$("#date1").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText,inst) {
        if(dateText !== inst.lastVal){
            if (inst.lastVal == '') {
                alert("User has selected: "+dateText);
            } else {
                alert("User has change "+inst.lastVal+" to "+dateText)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And my HTML code is just:
`<div id="date1"></div>`

Comment: Well, in your fiddle it works

Comment: @Pippo In the first one or the second one? In the first one it's supposed to work. In the second one, it doesn't...

Comment: Sorry, it was the first. It seems that lastValue is not set in the inline version.
See my answer for a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution, set your lastVal by yourself:

```
$("#date1").datepicker({

    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText,inst) {
    
        const myLastVal = inst.myLastVal || "";
        inst.myLastVal = dateText;
        
        if(dateText !== myLastVal){
            if (myLastVal == "") {
                alert("User has selected: " + dateText);
            } else {
                alert("User has change " + myLastVal + " to " + dateText)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tested it and it works! Thanks a lot! :)